# The requested URL /LearnPHP5/learnPHP.php was not found on this server

Tags: php, eclipse

I just downloaded Eclipse for Linux. Started a PHP tutorial and immediately hit a roadblock. The code is small:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello PHP World!';
```

When I run it as  web application, I get:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /LearnPHP5/learnPHP.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

I have the Web Developer Tools installed on Eclipse, PHP installed on my Linux. and Apache2 running. I have this same issue with NetBeans too. Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? I have tried everything seen on the SO posts regarding this, but nothing has remedied the situation. I've been trying to sort it out all day. Any help wld be greatly appreciated.

This is from my apache error log:

```
[Fri Dec 05 16:39:17.808812 2014] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 8660:tid 140438963517312] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 05 16:39:17.808955 2014] [core:notice] [pid 8660:tid 140438963517312] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Dec 05 16:39:31.664085 2014] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 8660:tid 140438963517312] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Dec 05 16:39:32.768582 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9978] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations  
[Fri Dec 05 16:39:32.768695 2014] [core:notice] [pid 9978] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

I'm open to all advice. Never seen such a dilemma over such a small amount of code.

Comment: This is likley a configuration... What is your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` in apache? Are your `LearnPHP` files in the directory? Note: if you are jsut using the Apache defaults then your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is probably `/var/www` on Ubuntu - so the file path on your system to the files should be `/var/www/LearnPHP5`

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm am very new to this. But index.php is not in /var/www. I did try to save it there but got permission denied as I was not root. Sorry for sounding so stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Look at log file (usually /var/log/apache2/error.log), where apache try to find your file /LearnPHP5/learnPHP.php .
It's seems like some mistake in the path to www root directory.

Comment: I put some of the apache log in my post for viewing. I'm not seasoned at any of this. So if anyone sees something that I need to do, please let me know. Thanks.